# ¿Cómo puedo llamar una matriz en C usando dos diferentes funciones?

Tags: c, funciones, fórmulas-de-matriz

En mi código tengo mi matriz ya delimitada, el usuario ingresará el número de filas y columnas. Sin embargo, mi problema es qué no he podido llamar a mi matriz desde otra función(void process() ).A continuación les presento mi código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
  int i,j,n,m,c1,c2;
  int r=n, x=m;
   int M[100][100];
 void disperso(int n,  int m)
 {
      for (i=0; i<n; i++){
      for (j=0; j<m; j++)
      printf("%d \t",M[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
     }  
  }             

 int main() {
 srand(time(0)); 
 int i,j,c;
 printf("\n Ingrese el numero de filas \n");
 scanf("%d", &n);
 printf("Ingrese el numero de columnas \n");
 scanf("%d",&m);
 printf("\n\n");
 int M[n][m];
    //Ciclos para rellenar matriz bidimensional
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (j=0; j<m; j++)
    M[i][j] = rand()%11;
    } 
    //Ciclos para imprimir matriz
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (j=0; j<m; j++)
    printf("%d \t",M[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    } 
    
  disperso( n,  m ); 
    }
```

Comment: Hay varios errores, C no usa namespace, la librería conio no es usada, el código no tiene sangría, hay código comentariado. Se presentan varios errores como por ejemplo al llamar la función ya que se define como (int, int, int [][]) y cuando es llamada están mal el orden de los parámetros. Adicional al definir el parámetro int M[][m] debería arrojar un error ya que m no está definido, estos son solo algunos de los errores que están en el código, quizás si corrigiera todo eso podría centrarme en el problema que tiene

Comment: Corregí varios aspectos, ahora elimine librería conio, puedo llamar la función, M esta definida y elimine el código que esta como comentario. En la función principal Main, relleno e imprimo mi matriz, y quiero imprimir esa misma matriz en mi segunda función void, pero solo obtengo ceros.

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido ese código, estás definiendo el array `M` en un ámbito global y local, decídete, lo declaras como local o global (si es global, no haría falta usar un parámetro para tener una referencia de la matriz) pero no lo puedes dejar así. Una cosa más, no uses [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), es inseguro y no es portatil (a esto me refiero a VLA: `int M[n][m];`). En vez de usar VLA, deberías de utilizar una matriz dinámica.